# Hive non consistent input file

Tags: input, hive

I have inconsistent log file which I would like to partition with Hive using dynamic partitioning. File example:

20/06/13 20:21:42.637 FLW CPTView::OnInitialUpdate nRemoveAppShareQSize0=50000\n
20/06/13 20:21:42.638 FLW \n
BandwidthGlobalSettings:Old Bandwidth common defines\n

Sometimes log file contains line which started with some word different from date. Each line delimited with \n.

I am running commands:

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_messages_temp (date STRING,time STRING,severity STRING,message STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\040' LOCATION '/examples/hive/tmp';`

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log_messages_partitioned (time STRING,severity STRING,message STRING) PARTITIONED BY (date STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\040' LOCATION '/examples/hive/partitions';`

`set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

FROM log_messages_temp pvs INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE log_messages_partitioned PARTITION(date) SELECT pvs.time, pvs.severity, pvs.message, pvs.date;`

As a result two dynamic partitions were created: date=20/06/13 and date=BandwidthGlobalSettings:Old

I would like to define to Hive to ignore lines started with not date string.

How can I do this? Or maybe exists another solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a UDF that will use regular expression to take only date format(ex: 20/06/13) and discard all others like "**BandwidthGlobalSettings:Old**" . You can use this UDF in your last query while inserting into final table.

I hope this explanation helps your requirement.